# How to correctly save documents in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am making a website where people can upload documents(.txt, .pdf, .docx, .rtf, etc.)  and then later download them. These documents can be from a 1 page essay to 50 page book. What is the correct way to save them? Do I just upload the whole file to a folder and save a link in the database pointing to that file? or do I get the text from the document and save it in a column in the database itself?

Comment: Largely depends on the context of your application. Many documents with a lot of data stored inside the database will make it bigger and if your app runs from an external provider you could face increasing cost to store all that data in a db while there is a flat price for disk space. Database backups and restore operations could also be a factor to consider and in any case it is not a programming problem.

Comment: What is the most efficient way?

Comment: There is more than one correct way.  If you are using SQL 2012 or later, you also have the option of a FileTable which provides the best of both worlds.